# Does dbWriteTable() perform a rollback if it fails during insert?

Tags: sql, r, rollback

I am working on a script that uses dbWriteTable from the DBI package in R and I was wanting to know what would happen if it fails during the write. For example let's say on the last row of the data frame there is an issue and it fails to write to the database, will it still write all the previous rows or will it rollback.

Comment: What exactly does your code look like? Did you put things inside a [transaction](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DBI/versions/0.5-1/topics/transactions)?

Comment: I did not have it inside a transaction at the time.